# TableViewCell with SegmentControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have tableview in which a particular cell has the UISegmentedControl in it.
My doubt is when a particular segment is selected I need to expand the cell and show the information below and need to hide it when the other segment is selected.

For Ex:
I have three segment A, B and C. When selecting the segment B, I need to show switch below the segment and when the other two segments are selected nothing must be displayed below the segment.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataSource's objects should have an "extended" property.

Each time a segmentedControl is changed, update your dataSource accordingly and reload your cell.

When you configure your cell, change its size depending on the "extended" property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few things to do here.  You need to make sure your tableview is using automatic dimension for its cell height.  Dont use the -heightForRowAtIndexPath method (remove it).  Instead set two properties on the tableview :

```
[self.tableview setEstimatedRowHeight:110];
[self.tableview setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
```

This enables proper autolayout (in case you havent already) for each cell.

You will need to have a subclass of UITableViewCell in code, if you havent already (sorry for skipping over some quite big things!). Add the information label to your cell in Interface Builder.  Give it a height constraint, and then drag this height constraint into your cell subclass so you can change it.

Now put your code for handling the segmented control in the subclass.  When you detect that the central segment has been selected, then affect the height constraint of your information label, like this :

```
self.labelHeightConstraint.constant = 40;
```

You may also need a call to setNeedsLayout :

```
[self setNeedsLayout];
```

Apologies for the brevity - hopefully this will point you in the right direction. There are some other details - for eg on -prepareForReuse method (on the cell) you can set the height of the info label to 0 (and call setNeedsLayout again).

Comment: Thanks, This is a great idea. Any how is this best approach to be used. What I have used is two cell,  one for segment and one for switch, I have added and deleted the switch cell when the segment changes.

Comment: Yes I'd say definitely this is the way to go.  Cells working with 'automatic dimension' is the most recent and best solution for cell sizes, so you should use that anyway.  Similarly its the best to use for expanding cells, so changing the constraint properties at run-time is definitely the best way to go.

Comment: BTW - the number used for the 'estimatedCellHeight' property - set this to a number closer to the size of your average cell.  All this actually does is give the table an idea of how many cells to prepare for a new table.